# Finding the area of the region bounded by the graphs of $y=|x|$, $y=|x|+3$, and $y=5-|x|$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, area, absolute-value

> Find the area of the region bounded by the graphs of $y = |x|$, $y = |x| + 3$, and $y = 5 - |x|$.

I got $\left(\dfrac{5\sqrt2}2\right)^2$, but this is incorrect.

I don't really understand what the problem means when they say "bounded" because there is a small region, and a big region that could both be interpreted as the "bounded region."

Any solution + clarification on what this bounded region is? Thanks.

Comment: What does the answer key say?

Comment: If you simplify $\left(\frac{5\sqrt2}2\right)^2$ you get $\frac{25}2$. Is this what your answer key says?

Comment: No, this is incorrect.

Comment: Does it say $\dfrac{21}2$?

Comment: Yes, very nice! I solved using your method! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the area of the square bounded by $(0,0), (\dfrac52,\dfrac52), (0,5), $ and $(-\dfrac52,-\dfrac52)$

minus the area of the square bounded by $(0,3),(1,4), (0,5), $ and $(-1,4)$.

(That small square is bounded by only two of the three graphs.)

The area of a square with diagonal length $d$ is $\dfrac{d^2}2$.

Can you use this information to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

The region is bounded by **each** of the three graphs. It is yellow in the enclosed picture.

[image]